# React Native Video play app local files using URI

Tags: react-native, video, drm, react-native-video

I am trying to play app-local DRM'ed video files using the [React Native Video DRM clone](https://github.com/24i/react-native-video/tree/feature/ios-drm-support) using the **source={uri: "file://rel-path"}** attribute and failing. I have used relative path, prefixed with `file://`  and without and non of its is working in both iOS and Android. I dont think I need file permissions for video files under `/src/assets` folder of my app?

My source code below :-

```
<Video
  source={{ uri: 'file://<relativepath>.mpd',
   drm: {
     type: 'widevine',
     licenseServer: 'https://proxy.uat.widevine.com/proxy?video_id=efd045b1eb61888a&provider=widevine_test', 
  }}
  style={styles.video}
/>
```

Comment: As far as what I can see in their doc, they only tested the over network video playing https://github.com/24i/react-native-video/blob/feature/ios-drm-support/DRM.md#provide-drm-data-only-tested-with-httphttps-assets